# Inserting data into database only by developer

Tags: database, android-studio, listview, android-database

I am creating an app which shows a list from database entries . The user can read or update the initial  entries but cannot insert any entries. How can insert values in database without having this feature on the working app ( limited to the developer ) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You must have rooted android device with the app installed
2. Go to location : `/data/data/<application_package_name>/databases`
   using any tool (you can do that on Android studio) you can find the
   database there
3. download it to your local machine
4. download SQLite server and run it on your local machine
5. copy the database to the SQLite server location
6. On the SQLite folder open command prompt (if you are on windows) and type
   sqlite3 YOUR_DB.db you can add any entry using SQL commands.
7. replace the old database with modified one